# how to restore woocommerce checkout fields after unseting them

Tags: woocommerce

I was trying to learn how to customize checkout fields. i use codes from [woocommerce docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/). try to unset billing field to see resualt.

i use this filter in construct method of my class:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , [$this, 'mycustomfields']);
```

and here is the function:

```
function hGhNewCheckoutFields($fields){
    unset($fields['billing']);
    return $fields;
}
```

it worked but i was just testing and i want billing fields back. i remove unset code but it didn't help. any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find an answer for it. first add `$fields['billing'] = null;` to the function.
refresh checkout page. then you can remove it and everything back to normal.
This happened because i unset `['billing']`. i should unset for example `['billing']['billing_email']` and repeat the code for other fields. by doing this you can have fields back by just deleting the unset code of that field.